# Get same field name values of two tables in join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables which is shipping address and billing address. i use join for these tables. but unfortunately the field name of two tables are same.I want to echo both data.

```
$this->db->select('a.*,b.*,c.*');
        $this->db->from('pr_order_products as a');
        $this->db->join('cust_bill_address as b','a.user_id = b.cust_id','inner');
        $this->db->join('cust_ship_address as c','a.user_id = c.cust_id','inner');
        $this->db->where($cond);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;
        return $query;
```

if i fetch the result and `echo $order->cust_id;` means it only takes from billing_address table.Is there any way to do?

Comment: You can use some Alias name.

Comment: yes...i don't think about it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the data fields explicitly in your select statement:

```
$this->db->select('
a.cust_id as a_cust_id,
b.cust_id as b_cust_id,
c.cust_id as c_cust_id, 
etc...');
```